# How does $\left(p+\frac{2-p^2}{r}\right)^2<2$ simplify to $2pr+2-p^2<r^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, problem-solving

How the inequality given below $$\left(p+\frac{2-p^2}{r}\right)^2<2$$ will eventually be simplified to the inequality $$2pr+2-p^2<r^2$$
I got the reference from this quora [Link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-explain-in-simple-easy-steps-the-reason-why-Walter-Rudin-chose-q-p-p-2-2-p-2-in-his-book-Principles-of-Mathematical-Analysis-to-prove-the-incompleteness-of-rationals/answer/Donald-Hartig?ch=15&oid=123817644&share=cdf16d79&srid=a3O3h&target_type=answer) .

Comment: Getting a common denominator and clearing fractions gives $$(pr+2-p^2)^2<2r^2 \quad \to\quad (pr+2-p^2)^2-2r^2<0$$
Expand the left, then re-factor the whole thing, and then note the condition from the link that $2-p^2>0$.

Comment: @Blue Yeah, thanks. After some rearrangements I got that inequality. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: *"After some rearrangements I got that inequality."* Great! Put your work into an answer (and accept it when you can), so that we can upvote your success and also so that the question disappears from the Unanswered queue.

Comment: @Blue Yeah, I have done it.

Answer (score 1):

As given $$\left(p+\frac{2-p^2}{r}\right)^2<2$$ we can simplify it as $$ (pr+2-p)^2-2r^2<0$$  $$\Rightarrow p^2r^2+4+p^4-4p^2+4pr-2p^3r-2r^2<0$$ $$\Rightarrow r^2(p^2-2)+2(2-p^2)-p^2(2-p^2)-2pr(p^2-2)<0$$ $$\Rightarrow -r^2(2-p^2)+2(2-p^2)-p^2(2-p^2)+2pr(2-p^2)<0$$ $$\Rightarrow (2-p^2)(-p^2+2+2pr-r^2)<0$$
From the link we knows that $$(2-p^2)>0$$ $$\Rightarrow -p^2+2+2pr-r^2<0$$ $$\Rightarrow 2pr+2-p^2<r^2$$